# Select only values that are in the table by maximum count on each id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

i have this SQL-Table for work scheduling:

| INTRAWORKNO | employee |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 40 |
| 1 | 45 |
| 2 | 40 |
| 2 | 45 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 55 |
| 3 | 40 |
| 3 | 45 |
| 3 | 50 |
| 3 | 55 |

What i want to have:

| INTRAWORKNO | employee |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 40 |
| 1 | 45 |
| 2 | 40 |
| 2 | 45 |
| 3 | 40 |
| 3 | 45 |

Explained:

With a select statement, I want to have these employees per Intraworkno, that suits the most.
Because on INTRAWORKNO 2 and 3 employees 50 and 55 are not allowed to do INTRAWORKNO 1, these should be not included in the select statement.
In INTRAWORKNO 0, employees 1 and 2 should remain, because there is no other option, that would be better.

I have tried it with something like

```
    SELECT employee, COUNT(INTRAWORKNO) as CNTINTRAWORKNO
FROM @persqualintrawork 
GROUP BY employee;
```

but I am not sure how I should join this with MAX function to remove unsuitable employees from the qry statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Do you always want two employees for each INTRAWORKNO?

Comment: @ThomA: no, when i `order by employee`, I get only one employee per INTRAWORKNO

Comment: how does sql knows this "Because on INTRAWORKNO 2 and 3 employees 50 and 55 are not allowed to do INTRAWORKNO 1, these should be not included in the select statement." logic from your example data? There's not enough info at all to solve your question, and stackoverflow is not a find waldo game

Comment: @jarlh: No, not specially two. e.g. when I have INSERT ... (INTRAWORKNO, employee) (1, 50), then there should be three values remaining for the entries INTRAWORKNO 1,2,3

Comment: @siggemannen: Because 50 and 55 employees dont have an entry with 1; I described it a bit confusing. Let`s say I want to remove 'unnecessary' employees, for this query, because when you look at this, this is a full workload with subworkloads 0,1,2.... Only the Employees 40 and 45 can do JOB 1, so why should they not do also the work of subworkload 2 and 3? It would be more useful, when 40 and 45 do more of the complete workload, instead 40 or 45 would do workload 1 and workload 2 or 3 would be done by another employee

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```sql
select *
from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Intraworkno ORDER BY sort DESC, employee) AS rnk
    ,   *
    from (
        select *, count(*) over(partition by employee) as sort
        from (
            VALUES  (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 40), (1, 45),(2, 40),(2, 45),(2, 50),(2, 55),(3, 40),(3, 45),(3, 50),(3, 55)
        ) t (INTRAWORKNO,employee)
    ) x
) x
WHERE rnk <= 2
```

This takes at most 2 employees per task, and sorts them by how many jobs they can do `count(*) over(partition by employee)` and then by the employee number: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Intraworkno ORDER BY sort DESC, employee)`

This is probably not perfect depending on the rest of your data but can be a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it:

```
    SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT INTRAWORKNO, MAX(CNT) as CNTT
    FROM @persqualintrawork persqualintrawork
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT employee, COUNT(INTRAWORKNO) as CNT
        FROM @persqualintrawork
        GROUP BY employee
    ) cntwork ON persqualintrawork.employee = cntwork.employee
    GROUP BY INTRAWORKNO
) AS CNTTmaxforeachINTRAWORKNO
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT innerqry.employee, CNT, persintrawork.INTRAWORKNO
    FROM
    (
        SELECT employee, COUNT(INTRAWORKNO) as CNT
        FROM @persqualintrawork
        GROUP BY employee
    ) as innerqry JOIN @persqualintrawork persintrawork ON innerqry.employee = persintrawork.employee
) as outerqry ON outerqry.INTRAWORKNO = CNTTmaxforeachINTRAWORKNO.INTRAWORKNO AND outerqry.CNT = CNTTmaxforeachINTRAWORKNO.CNTT
ORDER BY outerqry.INTRAWORKNO;
```

I had to get the `MAX` `COUNT` of INTRAWORKNO and then Join it with the `COUNT` of INTRAWORKNO